# What could be the derivative of the below

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{x\cos ^{-1}\left(x\right)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)$$

I have tried the below using uv and u/v rule however the expression is lengthy.

Can you help advise that is there any shortcut to proceed?

Comment: take $x=\cos\theta$

Comment: If I plugin x = cosθ, the above expression becomes, d/dx (θ*cotθ), the answer becomes, (arc cos x) (sin arc cos x) - (cos arx cos x). is that right?

Comment: $\dfrac{d}{dx}(\theta\cot\theta)=\dfrac{d}{d\theta}(\theta\cot\theta)\cdot\dfrac{d\theta}{dx}$

Comment: Correct, after the application of the rule, i got the below answer. Is that right? (arc cos x) (sin arc cos x) - (cos arx cos x)

Comment: $\dfrac{\cot\theta-\theta\csc^2\theta}{-\sin\theta}$,(now put $\theta=\arccos x$), I guess (I am bad at calculation, that is why I am not writing an answer...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way could be logarithmic differentiation

$$y=\frac{x \cos^{-1}(x)} {\sqrt{1-x^2}}\implies \log(y)=\log(x)+\log(\cos^{-1}(x))-\frac 12\log({1-x^2})$$ Differentiate both sides 
$$\frac{y'}y=\frac 1x +\frac{ \left(\cos^{-1}(x)\right)'} {\cos^{-1}(x) }-\frac 12\frac{\left({1-x^2}\right)' }{{1-x^2} }$$ When done $$y'=y \times \frac{y'}y$$ and simplify.

Comment: Which means the above answer and this answer contradicts. they are not same

Comment: I did not make any comment. I just providing another (easy) way to do the work.

Comment: Yeah, thanks! this appears to be correct!!

Comment: @AjeezMohd. This small trick is very useful when you face products, ratios, powers.